# How to control the URL format?

Tags: .htaccess

I need help with my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
            <remove statusCode="404"/>
            <error statusCode="404" path="/404.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
            <remove statusCode="500"/>
            <error statusCode="500" path="/index.cfm" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**.htaccess**

```
# Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file
# Version 3.0.0.29

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCompatibility2 On
RepeatLimit 200
RewriteBase 
# unsupported directive: [ISAPI_Rewrite]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http\://www.example.com$1 [NC,R=301,U]
RewriteRule ^/index.cfm$ http\://www.example.com [NC,R=301,U]
RewriteRule ^//index.cfm$ http\://www.example.com [NC,R=301,U]
```

Have both web.config and .htaccess

My site is opening on both the url format .. www. and non www and also with [www.example.com/index.cfm](http://www.example.com/index.cfm)

Want to open my site in the standard format http://www.example.com